# change background image and set cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, onclick

Trying to change the body background pattern to corresponding thumbnail clicked then save with cookie, switches fine but it doesn't save the cookie when I refresh the page.

Is this the right way to do it?

Can anyone help please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function changeBg(bgImage) {
                $("body").css({"background-image": bgImage});
                $.cookie("bgimg", bgImage, { expires: 7});
            }


            $('.bgswitch.pat1').click(function()
            {   
                changeBg("url(/images/patterns/p1.png)");
            });

            $('.bgswitch.pat2').click(function()
            {
                changeBg("url(/images/patterns/p2.png)"); 
            });
            $('.bgswitch.pat3').click(function()
            {
                changeBg("url(/images/patterns/p3.png)"); 
            });
            $('.bgswitch.pat4').click(function()
            {
                changeBg("url(/images/patterns/p3.png)"); 
            });
            $('.bgswitch.pat5').click(function()
            {
                changeBg("url(/images/patterns/p4.png)"); 
            });
            $('.bgswitch.pat5').click(function()
            {
                changeBg("url(/images/patterns/p5.png)"); 
            });
            $('.bgswitch.pat6').click(function()
            {
                changeBg("url(/images/patterns/p6.png)"); 
            });
            $('.bgswitch.pat7').click(function()
            {
                changeBg("url(/images/patterns/p7.png)"); 
            });
            $('.bgswitch.pat8').click(function()
            {
                changeBg("url(/images/patterns/p8.png)"); 
            });
            $('.bgswitch.pat9').click(function()
            {
                changeBg("url(/images/patterns/p9.png)"); 
            });
            $('.bgswitch.pat10').click(function()
            {
                changeBg("url(/images/patterns/p10.png)"); 
            });
</script>
```

Comment: How do you know the cookie isn't saved? I don't see where you're reading the cookie and setting the background on page load.

Comment: Also, that's a lot of code repetition. Find the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery ready event to set the background pattern at page refresh, like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").css({ "background-image": $.cookie("bgimg") });
});
```

also you can assign css class like "thumb" for all thumbnail images and optimise your code like

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   /* for page refresh */
   $("body").css({ "background-image": $.cookie("bgimg") });

   /* for thumbnail click event */
   $(".thumb").click(function(){
      $("body").css({"background-image": $(this).attr('src')});
      $.cookie("bgimg", "url("+ $(this).attr('src') +")", { expires: 7});
   });

});
```

That's all you need.

Comment: Note that you need jQuery cookie (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to do this.